# How i do make a vote system in roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

Does anyone know how to implement a voting system in roblox? I would like to know how to do specifically that when a player presses a button this adds 1 point and that he can change his vote but not add more than 1 point

I have created a button and a label

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you would do it in real life.

You check wether the player who pushes the button has pushed the button befor. Either by giving the player such an attribute or by maintaining a list of players who voted.
Only if the vote is valid take it into account.

Comment: Evento.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
 print("ejecutando evento")
 Pad1.Touched:Connect(function(player)
  if player.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
   print("funcionando tocado.")
   Pad1.Votes.Value = 1
   print(Pad1.Votes.Value)
   display1.Text = "Votes: "..tostring(Pad1.Votes.Value)
  end
 end)
end)

Comment: I have this code and I can make touching it add 1 vote point but I cannot make each player touch it add 1, since the times that different players touch it is and remains 1

Comment: well you assign 1 to it every time. what do you expect? you have add 1 to the value not assign 1, how else would the value increase?

Comment: The problem is that the votes when touching the players increase and do not stop increasing, I need to make each player can only add 1 point

Comment: update code: Evento.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
local function givePoints (otherpart)
  local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
  if player then
   print("funcionando tocado.")
   Pad1.Votes.Value = Pad1.Votes.Value+1
   print(Pad1.Votes.Value)
   display1.Text = "Votes: "..tostring(Pad1.Votes.Value)
   print("tocado")
  end
 end
 Pad1.Touched:Connect(givePoints)
end)

Comment: yeah then prevent this as I wrote in my answer. have a list who already voted or give each a player a property that shows you that he has no vote left or that he has cast his only vote or whatever.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a dictionary of votes keyed by player name. And any time a vote is updated, you iterate over all of the entries and recalculate the totals. That way you would know that any individual player's vote is only counted once, and you would also know who has and hasn't voted yet.